# List out all the client IP addresses that are currently connected to the server socket

Tags: java

i have  a server socket. Now there are two clients from 2 different machines connected to this server, which is in another machine. Is there any way to list out the ip addresses of these 2 client machines connected to the server?

Comment: u mena using java?. in linux u can simply try netsat

Comment: Yes, pure java. using server socket and client socket. is there a way to retrieve the ip addresses that are connected to the server socket?

Answer (score 3):

Not from the server socket itself. The only way would by to keep a reference to all `Socket`s created from connections that the server has accepted.

There may be other ways of identifing connections though, for example interrogating operating system's native networking APIs, but this depends on your OS and wouldn't be a good thing to put into a Java app.

Comment: Thanks for you reply!!! so there is no other methods where i can check what ip addresses is conneceted to the server socket?